# Program runs with gdb but doesn't run with ./ProgramName

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

I am writing an editor in assembly 64bit mode in linux. It runs correctly when I debug the program in GDB but it does not run correctly when I run it normally it means it has runtime errors when I use ./programName  .

Comment: Please give more details or shall we start guessing for all possible errors we have read/encountered? :)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably accessing uninitialized data or have some kind of memory corruption problem.  This would explain the program behaving differently when run in the debugger - you're seeing the results of undefined behavior.

Run your program through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)'s memcheck tool and see what it outputs.  Valgrind is a powerful tool that will identify many runtime errors on Linux, including a full stack trace to the error.

Answer (score 0):

If GDB disabling ASLR is what makes it work, perhaps `set disable-randomization off` in GDB will let your reproduce a crash inside GDB so you can debug it.  [Force gdb to load shared library at randomized address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944064/force-gdb-to-load-shared-library-at-randomized-address).

Otherwise enable core dumps from your program, and use GDB on the core dump.
`gdb ./prog core.1234`.

On x86, you can insert a `ud2` instruction in your asm source to intentionally cause a crash at whatever point you want in your code, if you want to get a coredump to examine registers/memory at some point before it crashes on its own.  All architectures have an undefined instruction you can use, but I only know the mnemonic for x86's off the top of my head.