# Running versus stepping in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

The very same piece of code works properly if I step into each call from beginning to end,
but behaves completely differently if I just run the program with no breakpoints. This
different behavior ultimately leads to an exit(1) which is used to notify a logical error
from which it is not possible to recover.

I believe my program should be working, but due to threading issues which happen at a
different speed while running and stepping, the program crashes when running. I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 and I'm writing an OpenGL Game with Automatic Reference Counting. The problem arises in
pretty standard C code which I wrote, with no explicit threading calls, just plain procedural C pointer arithmetic.

Why does this happen?

Comment: We need more details to be able to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program runs with gdb but doesn't run with ./ProgramName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274451/program-runs-with-gdb-but-doesnt-run-with-programname)