# Force gdb to load shared library at randomized address

Tags: gdb, aslr

I'm debugging a shared library. I found that the bug can be trigger when I enable ASLR in Linux host, while the bug disappears when ASLR is disabled.

I want to further debug the shared library with gdb. But I found it always loaded the shared library at a fixed address, which made the bug disappear.

Is there any way to disable this gdb's feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable this gdb's feature?

Yes, you can `set disable-randomization off` before running the program.
See this part of [gdb documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html):

> set disable-randomization off
>
> Leave the behavior of the started executable unchanged. Some bugs rear their ugly heads only when the program is loaded at certain
>   addresses. If your bug disappears when you run the program under GDB,
>   that might be because GDB by default disables the address
>   randomization on platforms, such as GNU/Linux, which do that for
>   stand-alone programs. Use set disable-randomization off to try to
>   reproduce such elusive bugs.